# Get data from a table based on a table name as a field value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select from different tables by selecting id from Table_1.

I tried using

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Table_Name FROM Table_1 WHERE id = 1)
```

to print out all records from topics_tbl.

Table_1 :

```
id  Table_Name      
1   topics_tbl
2   teachers_tbl
```

topics_tbl:

```
id topics
1  English
2  Math
3  Science
```

teachers_tbl:

```
id first_Name last_Name
1  John       Dowe
2  Joe        Smith 
3  Mary       Lee
```

Comment: You seem to need some help. We are willing to provide some help but first you have to actually provide us with a question. As posted it does not make any sense at all what you are trying to do here.

Comment: The table meta data needs some work. The current relational tables do not relate teachers to topics. There needs to be a topic_id column in the teachers_tbl or a link table that relates teachers to their topics(s). You'll need to decide if a given teacher can teach more than one topic. If so, I would use a link table that supports a one to many relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dynamic query as below and execute it with help of `EXECUTE sp_executesql`

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(256), @sqlString VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @tableName=Table_Name FROM Table_1 WHERE id = 1;

SET @sqlString = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlString
```

[sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: You can do by `WHERE id = @idParam` and `@idParam` here is the parameter